# How can I establish as much airflow from my house to outdoors as possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, airflow, temperature, air

I live in a small flat with all doors and windows sealed. The temperature outside is moderately cold. I assume the temperature in my flat is hotter because my body and the computer are emitting heating.

If I open the window slightly and turn on the air condition to a very high temperature will air move entirely from my house to outdoors?

Basically, I want "fresh" air to come from the air condition and move outside as fast possible. I will need outdoors to act as a vacuum cleaner sucking up all the air from my flat rapidly.

I need the effect to be exaggerated. When I put my finger on the slightly open window I want to feel the pressure sucking it towards outside.

Comment: By fresh, do you mean cool or new air?

Comment: I mean new hot air.

Comment: (1) Most modern air conditioning systems do not exchange air between inside and outside, they pump *heat* from one side to the other. (2) When you "feel the pressure sucking it [your finger] towards outside" where do you think that the replacement air for your room will come from? (3) Why don't you just open the windows and get free cooling? (4) *"I will need outdoors to act as a vacuum cleaner sucking up all the air from my flat rapidly."* Air will move due to pressure difference.

Comment: The outside will not work as a vacuum so you need to either (a) raise the pressure inside the house or (b) use an extract fan but you still need air to get in somewhere else. There's an edit link below your question ...

Comment: There are two types of air conditioners: refrigerative & evaporative. Evaporative are usually large boxes on roofs which move air from outside to inside but pass air through a water saturated filter/screen. They need to have an external door or window open when operating, for flow through ventilation. They also increase the humidity inside & are only really useful for dry climates. Refrigerative ACs are sealed units that transfer heat from one side of a wall to the other side. I suspect your AC is refrigerative so it won't do what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

As @Transistor has commented air conditioning systems don't add fresh air, they recycle the air. Because the return air going back to the air conditioner requires much less energy to be brought back to the thermostat setting then outside cold temperature.

Also modern system are very efficient and do their job by streamlining the system so that distribution of the conditioned air doesn't require a big fan/ blower.

If you feel you need more fresh air than what by code must be provided to your space, you can install a fan in a exterior wall location far from the air conditioner return so that your fan doesn't impede your air conditioner's job.

As a note, sometimes these situations are a sign of asthma or some similar medical issue. you may want to ask a doctor.